# git-upload-pack not found when deploying

Tags: git, github-pages

When I'm trying to deploy my react app to github pages, I ran `npm run deploy`. It managed to build but has the following errors when deploying:

```
git-upload-pack '.': git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

My `git remote -v` returns:

```
origin  https://github.com/helplah/shopping-cart.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/helplah/shopping-cart.git (push)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to solve it by looking at other answers here. First, you type `which git-upload-pack` to find out if git has access to it.

If it does not, on Windows 7 you have to go control panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> edit path. Over there add the path of git-upload-pack.

git-upload-pack is usually in `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` or `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core`. You can find it in `\Git\mingw64`.

I added both paths and after restarting my computer it worked for me.

Comment: thanks, i try to find the solution for a lot of blogs but this hel me.

Comment: best answer.. I looked atleast 10 blogs but none of them worked.